# Dynamic Routes from sql database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am quite new to ASP.NET Core and routing and I am looking for an advice. In the old days I would have a page like CMS or `page.aspx`.

My main question is how would I go about creating a unique url off the route, i.e. www.mydomain.com/test-page or if they pick a sub category www.mydomain.com/cat/page.

I know it kinda has to do with routes, but I do not know how one makes them dynamic. Any advice be appreciated. I am using ASP.NET Core 1.2.

Also I want to be able to give the end user ability to pick from certain views, i.e. kinda of like how you could have done with master pages.

**Edit Correction**
Hi folks sorry for confusion this is asp.net core app 1.1 not version 2 as pointed out to me below

I have a controller called CMS controller

```
private solitudeDContext _context;

    public CmsController(solitudeDContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public IActionResult GetContent(string slug)
    {

        CmsPages _page = new CmsPages();

        _page= _context.Pages.Where(w=>w.slug==slug).Select(s=>s.Content).Single();


    }
}
```

Class for CMS pages

```
public  class CmsPages
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

     public string slug { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string PageView { get; set; }

    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }

    public bool isVisible { get; set; }



    public string Creator { get; set; }

    public PageStatus PageStatuses { get; set; }

}
```

**Edit 2**

Ok so i tried the following

```
    private solitudeDContext _context;

    public CmsController(solitudeDContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public IActionResult GetContent(string slug)
    {

        CmsPages _page = new CmsPages();

       var  _content= _context.Pages.Where(w=>w.slug==slug).Select(s=>s.Content).Single();

        return View();

    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

And in my view its just showing a blank page am i missing something must I have  a view as well cms for this ?.

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "cmsroute",
              template: "{slug}"
              , defaults: new { controller = "Cms", action = "GetContent" }
              );
```

Comment: There is no ASP.NET Core 1.2. Only 1.0.x, 1.1.x and 2.0 previews

Comment: Also what's **not working** with the above approach? Using the slug seems the correct way, as you do not want to add/remove/modify the route tables once the application as started. Routes should only be configured at the startup, as frequently changing the routings is bad performance wise

Comment: Hi @Tseng I am just asking what is considered best practise how would one tell core to get the slug from the db and to turn the current url into correct one.

Comment: @Tseng I made a edit to show correction to version number above sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a route something like this in Startup.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "cmsroute",
           template: "{slug}"
           , defaults: new { controller = "Cms", action = "GetContent" }
           );
```

Note also rather than build your own new cms you might find my project [cloudscribe.SimpleContent](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.SimpleContent) is useful to you, even if you do want to build your own you can study the code and get ideas on how to do things

Comment: Hi joe would I not need to add something in the method it self to tell its the path thanks for that, and no I cant its a thing for internal project mate, u no what boses are like this is just a learning curve for me to be honest that used ot webforms.

Comment: also what does template do i want to be able to set the view based on a field called PageTemplate in the class.

Comment: template is the pattern for the url to match, see the documentation about routing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing

Comment: would that take into the slug being off the root of the domain @joe